# Cannot start SQL Server express

Tags: sql-server-express

I want to start SQL Server 2017 Express and enter the command

```
"D:\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\Binn\sqlservr.exe" -sSQLEXPRESS
```

The following error message appeared. How to solve the problem?

```
2018-11-28 10:06:25.72 spid5s      Uploading data collector package from disk: d:\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\Install\SqlTraceCollect.dtsx
2018-11-28 10:06:25.72 spid5s      Uploading data collector package from disk: d:\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\Install\SqlTraceCollect.dtsx
2018-11-28 10:06:25.72 spid5s      Error: 2775, Severity: 17, State: 12.
2018-11-28 10:06:25.72 spid5s      The code page 65001 is not supported by the server.
2018-11-28 10:06:25.74 spid5s      Error: 912, Severity: 21, State: 2.
2018-11-28 10:06:25.74 spid5s      Script level upgrade for database 'master' failed because upgrade step 'msdb110_upgrade.sql' encountered error 200, state 7, severity 25. This is a serious error condition which might interfere with regular operation and the database will be taken offline. If the error happened during upgrade of the 'master' database, it will prevent the entire SQL Server instance from starting. Examine the previous errorlog entries for errors, take the appropriate corrective actions and re-start the database so that the script upgrade steps run to completion.
2018-11-28 10:06:25.74 spid5s      Error: 3417, Severity: 21, State: 3.
2018-11-28 10:06:25.74 spid5s      Cannot recover the master database. SQL Server is unable to run. Restore master from a full backup, repair it, or rebuild it. For more information about how to rebuild the master database, see SQL Server Books Online.
2018-11-28 10:06:25.74 spid5s      SQL Server shutdown has been initiated
2018-11-28 10:06:25.74 spid5s      SQL Trace was stopped due to server shutdown. Trace ID = '1'. This is an informational message only; no user action is required.
```

Comment: *2018-11-28 10:06:25.74 spid5s      Cannot recover the master database. SQL Server is unable to run. **Restore master from a full backup, repair it, or rebuild it. For more information about how to rebuild the master database, see SQL Server Books Online.***

Comment: What OS? Has this ever started before? Does this help? https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/217759/error-starting-sql-server-2017-service-error-code-3417

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

control panel > Region and Time

and try as u see in this:

[image]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).